# Equal Stretch Columns in QTableView

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have a question abour QtDesigner.

I have created a QTableView and filled it with 3 columns. The probleme is that I dont find the option to strech them :

[image: QTableView with non streched columns]
I saw that I can stretch the last one but that all.

Any Idea on how can I make that ?

Comment: Not sure if this is possible from within Qt Designer, but you can do this programmatically via `QTableView.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(i, QHeaderView.Stretch)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Heike for the answer :

```
for i in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
    self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(i, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
```